# Rearrange a number into alphabetical order

Tags: code-golf, number, sorting

Given a non-negative integer (`n`), create a function that returns `n` in alphabetical order, according to the literal spelling of each digit in `n`.

#### Examples:

```
Input: 101
>> one, zero, one
>> one, one, zero
Output: 110

Input: 31948
>> three, one, nine, four, eight
>> eight, four, nine, one, three
Output: 84913

Input: 5544
>> five, five, four, four
>> five, five, four, four
Output: 5544

Input: 1234567890
Output: 8549176320
```

Note: the operations in the example are illustrative only and do not need to be included in the output. Only the alphabetically-sorted number needs to be returned.

This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Edit: the input can be taken in any desired format that best suits your language, and the output can be produced similarly by returning from the function or printing. The input will always be a natural number (including 0) and will not contain leading 0's.

[Relevant OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A057846) (A057846) found by @DomHastings

Comment: Can I also take the number as a string and output a string?

Comment: @nimi `00` ....

Comment: @atlasologist May we print the output?

Comment: @xnor returned from function or printed--either seems fine.

Comment: You might want to specify that the input is in decimal, or you'll get some cheeky answers using unary...

Comment: @nimi `00` doesn't need to be handled.

Comment: Multi digit strings "one hundred two"?

Comment: This is a bit confusing: you wrote in the comments that you expect a numeric type as input and output of the function, but also that it’s okay to print the result instead. So, if the output is `849`, does that mean we’re allowed to print the number `849` but not the string `"849"`? IMO this is just a [cumbersome I/O format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/3852) (bad!) on top of a perfectly fine challenge.

Comment: Leading zeroes significant or not? e.g. what does `001` output? If they are significant and the result is not `1`, most languages will require strings as input for the simple fact it is crude, impractical and usually nigh on impossible to ask the parser to preserve leading zeroes in base 10 literal numbers.

Comment: @Cat, input will be natural numbers with no leading 0's.

Comment: Of course there's an OEIS entry: [Obsessive Filer's Sequence](https://oeis.org/A057846)

Comment: @DomHastings wow, nice find!

Answer (score 12):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>32</s>  28 bytes

```perl6
{+[~] .comb.sort: *.Str.uniname}
{+[~] .comb.sort: *.uniname}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  # turn the following into a Numeric
  +

  # fold the following list using string concatenation operator
  [~]

    # split $_ into individual characters
    # (implicit method call on implicit parameter)
    .comb

    .sort:
    *.uniname # sort by the Unicode name of the character (digit)
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
  101 => 110,
  31948 => 84913,
  5544 => 5544,
  1234567890 => 8549176320,
);

# give the lambda a lexical name for clarity
my &int-sort = {+[~] .comb.sort: *.uniname}

plan 3 * @tests;

for @tests -> $_ ( :key($input), :value($expected) ) {
  put '';
  isa-ok $input, Int, "input ($input) is an Int";

  my $output = int-sort $input;

  is $output, $expected, .gist;
  isa-ok $output, Int, "output ($output) is an Int"
}
```

```perl6
1..12

ok 1 - input (101) is an Int
ok 2 - 101 => 110
ok 3 - output (110) is an Int

ok 4 - input (31948) is an Int
ok 5 - 31948 => 84913
ok 6 - output (84913) is an Int

ok 7 - input (5544) is an Int
ok 8 - 5544 => 5544
ok 9 - output (5544) is an Int

ok 10 - input (1234567890) is an Int
ok 11 - 1234567890 => 8549176320
ok 12 - output (8549176320) is an Int
```

Answer (score 8):

### 05AB1E, <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
•OWÿ¾•vy†J
```

**Explained**

```
•OWÿ¾•        # push sortorder (236719458)
      v       # for each number in sortorder
       y†     # filter to the front
         J    # join
              # implicitly print
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCiT1fDv8K-4oCidnnigKBK&input=MzE5NDg)

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54

*Edit* same char count, but avoiding the global variable `z`

Input / output as strings

```
n=>[...n].sort((a,b)=>n[a]-n[b],n='9487216503').join``
```

**Test**

```js
f=n=>[...n].sort((a,b)=>n[a]-n[b],n='9487216503').join``

function test() {
  O.textContent=f(I.value)
}

test()
```

```html
<input id=I type=number value=31948 oninput='test()'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Love this, using the input digits as indices of the string `z`...

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>62 51</s> 44 bytes

As @nimi suggested, using a list comprehension is shorter than composing functions:

```
f x=0+read[a|a<-"8549176320",b<-show x,a==b]
```

For reference my version:

```
f n=read.(=<<)(\x->filter(==x)$show n)$"8549176320"
```

The pointfree version is a bit longer:

```
f=flip(read.)"8549176320".(=<<).flip(filter.(==)).show
```

Straightforward: Filter the digits in the correct order and then concatenate the result.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
ox`C" »Ä\0
```

Not sure if it can be golfed further. Input needs to be enclosed in quotes.

2 bytes saved thanks to @isaacg!

In pythonic pseudocode:

```
                Q = input()
o          Q    sort(Q, key = lambda N:
  `C" »Ä\0        repr(base256toDec(" »Ä\0"))
 x        N         .index(N)     # 8 being absent from the number yields -1
                )
```

[Test it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ox%60C%22+%C2%BB%C3%84%5C0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22101%22%0A%2231948%22%0A%225544%22&debug=0).

Comment: @busukxuan I also get [14 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#ox%60%2aC%5C%E8%B0%80C%5C%E3%AF%9B) :p.

Comment: @Adnan revert to numbers then. It seems there isn't a way to compress these numbers...

Comment: Save 2 bytes by replacing `549176320` with `C" »Ä\0`

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! I tried to convert it to base 256 a few times but the result was wrong. How did you do it right?

Comment: You have to escape null bytes by replacing them with `\0`. That's probably the problem you were running into.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 37 bytes

36 bytes code + 1 byte command line (-F)

```
say sort{8549176320=~/$b.*$a/||-1}@F
```

Usage example:

```
echo -n "04823" | perl -F -M5.010 entry.pl
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>35 78</s> 47 bytes

31 bytes saved thanks to a suggestion by LIAMnYP!

```
FromDigits@SortBy[IntegerDigits@#,IntegerName]&
```

`IntegerDigits` breaks up the number into digits which are then sorted according to their names in English. `FromDigits` assembles the digits into a base-10 number.

---

```
FromDigits@SortBy[IntegerDigits@#,IntegerName]&[1234567890]
```

8549176320

Comment: By using "SortBy" you don't have the problem of converting the words back to digits. `FromDigits@SortBy[IntegerName]@IntegerDigits@#&`

Comment: Also `Interpreter` is painfully slow, so that's an added bonus.

Comment: Fantastic improvement.

Comment: 11 bytes in Mtmca, whenever that comes into being.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>142</s> <s>141</s> 117

Pass parameter as `long long *` to `f()`; the function modifies the parameter:

```
f(long long*n){char*c="8549176320",g[10]={0};for(;*n;*n/=10)++g[*n%10];for(;*c;++c)for(;g[*c-48]--;*n=*n*10+*c-48);}
```

`long long` is necessary since the last test case overflowed an `int` when sorted.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
Vt'8549176320'&m2$S
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=VnQnODU0OTE3NjMyMCcmbTIkUw&input=MzE5NDg)

#### Explanation

```
V              % Implicitly input number. Convert to string (¹)
t              % Push copy of (¹)
'8549176320'   % Push this string (²), which defines order
&m             % Indices (³) of each element of (¹) in (²)
2$S            % Sort copy of (¹) according to (³). Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“U1°ŀ”OṾf@€
```

[Try it here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcVTHCsMWA4oCdT-G5vmZA4oKs&input=&args=IjMxOTQ4Ig)

### Explanation

```
“U1°ŀ”O       Get the Unicode ordinals of “U1°ŀ”
                (all of which are coincidentally single bytes
                in the Jelly code page!)
              The result is [85, 49, 176, 320].
       Ṿ      Uneval. This gets us the string “85,49,176,320”.
        f@€   For each char in this string, extract all chars
                from the first command line argument that
                equal it.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2 - 95 bytes

```
def s(n):
    l=list("8549176320")
    return "".join(sorted(list(n),key=lambda x: l.index(x)))
```

Attempting further golfing...I think the line 2 is unnecessary and this can become 1 lambda.

EDIT: 49 char version in comments, thx to xnor and vaultah for help.

Comment: `lambda n:''.join(sorted(\`n\`,key="8549176320".find))`

Comment: @vaultah Nice solution, you should post it! I think you can omit the `8` so that the `find` gives -1.

Comment: ooh that's clever @xnor. The shortest I got it to was `lambda n: "".join(sorted(n,key="549176320".find))`, which is really similar to what you suggested, vaultah. You should post it!

Comment: @Jeremy You should edit that version into your post.

Comment: At least get rid of the superfluous whitespace... Indentation can be done with a single space. Also this is invalid, because the [OP stated](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84814/rearrange-a-number-into-alphabetical-order#comment207904_84814) that output must be a numeric type.

Comment: @vaultah That fails for values above `sys.maxint`, because `repr(long_value)` appends an `L` to the end.

Comment: Needlessly long imo but +1 for a beginner :)

Comment: @Mego No need to use Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

**-- Oracle 11 (SQL): 164 bytes**

```
  SELECT LISTAGG(DECODE(s,0,'zero',TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(s,'j'),'jsp')),',')WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1)FROM(SELECT SUBSTR(&1,level,1)s FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(&1));
```

**Long form and explanation**

```
  SELECT LISTAGG(DECODE(s,0,'zero',TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(s,'j'),'jsp')),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)
  FROM ( SELECT SUBSTR(&1,level,1)s FROM dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(&1)
        );
```

Get the input as parameter to script:

```
  SELECT &1 FROM dual
```

"create" rows by using connect by based on length of input:

```
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(&1)
```

Rip out each digit from the string for each position:

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(&1,level,1)s FROM dual
```

Convert the digit to Julian date, and back to Char to get spelling:

```
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(s,'j'),'jsp')
```

Check for zero - special case.

```
  DECODE(s,0,'zero'
```

Use LISTAGG function to concatenate rows back into a single row list, comma delimited, ordered alphabetically

```
  LISTAGG(DECODE(s,0,'zero',TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(s,'j'),'jsp')),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)
```

Always fun trying to tweak SQL for things like this ... :) really tests my knowledge of the bugger ...

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, <s>142</s> 130 bytes

```
(λ(n)(string->number(list->string(sort(string->list(~a n))char<? #:key(λ(m)(string-ref "9487216503"(-(char->integer m)48)))))))
```

Of which conversions are <s>more than</s> *almost* half of the length (<s>76</s> 64 bytes).

Comment: `(+ 1 answer)` for Racket!

Comment: @cat It's useful for me to keep practicing Racket, since it's a way to maintain functional programming knowledge while working on these horribly procedural legacy Java (and slightly-less-legacy Python) programs left to me by my co-workers.  I could rant about how having objects does not necessarily make a program object-oriented, but instead of doing that I'll just keep golfing my problems away in Racket.

Comment: Hmm... I definitely sympathise, and it's possible and fun to write functional Python, but Java's just Fawful. Maybe you can get your superiors to let you use Scala for the implementation and Java just as glue. :)

Comment: By the way, if you like Forth and your eyes get a little tired from reading Lisp inside-out, you should check out [Factor](https://factorcode.org), which is Lisp and the CLOS but in a Forth-y postfix and point-free disguise.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 60 bytes

```
->n{n.to_s.chars.sort_by{|c|'8549176320'.index c}.join.to_i}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL, 260 bytes

Used reversed bubble sort to avoid refering to the length, to save some bytes

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @ varchar(99)=101

,@i INT=99,@j INT=98WHILE @i>1SELECT
@=IIF(CHARINDEX(x,'598327614')>CHARINDEX(y,'598327614'),STUFF(STUFF(@,@j,1,x),@i,1,y),@),@i-=IIF(@j=1,1,0),@j=IIF(@j=1,@i,@j-1)FROM(SELECT
SUBSTRING(@,@i,1)x,SUBSTRING(@,@j,1)y)z
PRINT @
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @s BIGINT=1234567890

DECLARE @ char(99)=@s,@i INT=99,@j INT=98
WHILE @i>1
  SELECT 
    @=IIF(CHARINDEX(x,'236719458')>CHARINDEX(y,'236719458'),
        STUFF(STUFF(@,@j,1,x),@i,1,y),@), 
    @i-=IIF(@j=1,1,0),
    @j=IIF(@j=1,@i,@j-1)
  FROM(SELECT SUBSTRING(@,@i,1)x,SUBSTRING(@,@j,1)y)z
PRINT CAST(@ as bigint)
```

Insisting on using integer types as input and output added 37 bytes

Comment: `DECLARE @ varchar(99)=101` 0.o does `101` get turned to a string automatically?

Comment: Also, `stuff` is an objectively awful function name. `squash` or `shove` or `pack` would be better :P

Comment: @cat yes, it gets converted into a string automatically, but that would be cheating according to the descriptino. I agree, stuff is a silly name

Comment: I mean, we might as well just call every function `stuff` cause that's what functions do: they do stuff. Then your code can look like `stuff(stuff(4, 5, stuff), stuff(stuff()).(stuff())()); stuff(stuff)`

Answer (score 1):

## ClojureScript, 45 bytes

```
#(apply str(sort-by(vec"9487216503")(str %)))
```

Uses some screwy string->int conversion from Javascript leak through, so it's not valid Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

### Firebird, 317 bytes

**Golfed:**

```
select list(s,'')from(with recursive q as(select 1 p,substring(:a from 1 for 1)s from rdb$database q union all select q.p+1 p,substring(:a from q.p+1 for 1)s from q where q.p<char_length(:a))select s from q order by iif(s=8,0,iif(s=5,1,iif(s=4,2,iif(s=9,3,iif(s=1,4,iif(s=7,5,iif(s=3,7,iif(s=2,8,iif(s=0,9,6))))))))))
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
select list(s, '')
from (
   with recursive q as (
      select 1 as p, substring(:a from 1 for 1) s
      from rdb$database q
      union all
      select q.p + 1 as p, substring(:a from q.p + 1 for 1) as s
      from q
      where q.p < char_length(:a)
   )
   select s
   from q
   order by iif(s = 8, 0,
               iif(s = 5, 1,
                  iif(s = 4, 2,
                     iif(s = 9, 3,
                        iif(s = 1, 4,
                           iif(s = 7, 5,
                              iif(s = 3, 7,
                                 iif(s = 2, 8,
                                    iif(s = 0, 9, 6)))))))))
)
```

There's no split functionality in Firebird. Instead I created a recursive query to get the next character over and over. Then reselect those while sorting by our proper order. Finally concatenate those results back together in a list. Override the default comma delimiter with blank. I could save 11 bytes by creating a new dummy table instead of `rdb$database` but I thought that may be against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

### ZX Spectum, machine code, <s>53</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
    org 49200 ; #c030

; table converts ascii to alfabetical order
; start from BASIC with any number as : PRINT "1234567890" AND USR 49208
```

`convtab defb 249 ; zero
        defb 244 ; one
        defb 248    ; two
        defb 247 ; three
        defb 2+205 ; four
        defb 1+205 ; five
        defb 246 ; six
        defb 245 ; seven
    ;    defb 0 ; eight
    ;   defb 3 ; nine
    ; last 2 conversions hidden in call-command`

```
start Call #2bf1    ; fetch stackindex
    call #2ab2 ; store back
    ld h,#c0    ; set highbyte of table


Sort Push de
loop ld b,d
    ld c,e
    inc de
    ld a,(bc)   ; fetch number
    Ld l,a
    ld a,(de)
    cp 34       ; endmarker "
    Jr z,exit   ; end reached?
    push hl     ; save number
    ld l,a
    Ld a,(hl)   ; convert second number
    pop hl
    cp (hl)     ; compare numbers
    jr nc,loop  ; in order, no swap
swap ld a,(bc)  ; swap original numbers
    ld l,a
    ld a,(de)
    ld (bc),a
    ld a,l
    ld (de),a
Exit pop de
    Ret z
    jr sort     ; check number for order
```

Comment: With Gnome-sort it can be shortened and table can be 1 byte shorter. New version to come...

Comment: Gnome-sort here is longer, but other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 128

```
[ 10 base> [ 48 - ] { } map-as dup [ number>text ] map zip [ second first ] sort-with [ first ] map [ 48 + ] ""map-as 10 >base ]
```

Hooray for builtins! :D

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 126 bytes

As far as I know php doesn't have any builtins that would really help with this (the best I could do using a usort(str_split()) was 5 bytes longer) so the only thing I'm happy within this answer is the games played with $i to save a couple of bytes on the itteration.

```
<?php for($i=-1;$i<9;)$a[++$i]=preg_replace("/[^$i]/","",$argv[1]);array_multisort([9,4,8,7,2,1,6,5,0,3],$a);echo implode($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 23 bytes

```
{⍎n['8549176320'⍋n←⍕⍵]}
```

Explanation:

- `n←⍕⍵`: get the string representation of `n` and store it in `n`
- `'8549176320'⍋`: find a permutation of `n` that sorts `n` given the order `8549176320`.
- `n[`...`]`: reorder `n` by that permutation
- `⍎`: evaluate the result (to turn it back into a number)

Comment: Since I/O may be strings, you can remove `⍎` and `⍕`. Convert to tradfn by removing `{` and `}` and substituting `⍞` for `⍵`. Finally, remove `0` as unlisted sorts at the end: `n['854917632'⍋n←⍞]`

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 53 bytes

Well, list comprehension idea from Haskell solution seems to be the shortest:

```
#(apply str(for[p"8549176320"b(str %):when(= p b)]p))
```

My original approach is 1 byte longer:

```
#(apply str(sort-by(zipmap"549176320"(range))(str %)))
```

You can see both function online here: https://ideone.com/afac5n

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, 104

```
(lambda(n)(#1=parse-integer(sort(format()"~A"n)'string<= :key(lambda(u)(format()"~R"(#1#(string u)))))))
```

#### Ungolfed

```
(lambda (n)
  (parse-integer
   (sort (format nil "~A" n)
         #'string<=
         :key (lambda (u) (format nil "~R" (parse-integer (string u)))))))
```

Convert integer as string, sort characters using the `string<=` comparison while using a custom `:key` function which converts a given character as the English representation of the numerical value it represents. Usually I would not use a key function which does as much as this one, but it costs less in bytes than decorate/sort/undecorate.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 234 bytes

This is a direct translation of [my Factor answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84840/46231), just for fun.

```
def f(n):
 s=list(map(int,str(n)))
 return int("".join(list(map(str,list(map(lambda x:x[1],sorted(list(zip(list(map(lambda t:{0:"zero",1:"one",2:"two",3:"three",4:"four",5:"five",6:"six",7:"seven",8:"eight",9:"nine"}[t],s)),s)))))))))
```

The semantics of the evaluation of "lazy" map and zip objects is the most subtle hard-to-find-bug-inducing piece of genuine horse excrement in the universe. Sometimes, `s = map(f, x)` won't allow `s` to be used properly or at all.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 74 bytes

```python
lambda x:''.join(i[1]for i in sorted(['9487216503'[int(j)],j]for j in x))
```

Comment: You might be able to save some bytes by using a lambda

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 14 bytes

```
.#uЀB`@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.%23u%04%D0%80%1B%05%EF%86%93B%60%40&input=%221234567890%22)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7.11, 67 bytes

```python
lambda n:''.join(sorted(list(n),key=lambda s:"9487216503"[int(s)]))
```

Takes a string as input and outputs a string.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 80 bytes

Takes a string containing a number in base 10 and prints to `stdio`:

```
F(char*i){for(char*p,d,*o="8549176320";*o;++o)for(p=i;d=*p++;d-*o||putchar(d));}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 107 bytes

```php
function($a){usort($a,function($a,$b){return($z=array_flip([8,5,4,9,1,7,6,3,2,0]))[$a]-$z[$b];});return$a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xa8MwEIV3/YojaLDgCnYdNw5KyFToUGh2VQTFkbEhjYQsD43xb3fPcYfc9N69u@/5xk@7g2888AB7mOr@VsXW3RJuxNB3LkRS@LRFfhZDsLEP5O57E4L5PdXX1ieqxALXuMUMN/iGOb5iqoVQ3OgXflf8rOUo5PLKjRwnyXi0XeyoVzEAlWGKmcZZ5gTZEqxcbPEgrxeTETgnW1DJBku6SynQkrHaBWuqJoF/rulIgYCB3mzVOGh//NVdbPJYI6xgnu@4wqckLOmcHz@Op/evT8lGNv0B)

Uses a user-defined comparison function to adjust the sorting order.

***Output***

```php
101         110
31948       84913
5544        5544
1234567890  8549176320
```